# What does "##vso" mean in Azure pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash

I can find an official doc explains this. Please help.

Comment: Visual Studio Online     It is not explicitly listed there but the history section at Wikipedia brings back many memories...  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azure_DevOps_Server#:~:text=On%2Dpremises%20vs.-,online,the%20Microsoft%20Azure%20cloud%20platform

Comment: vso = virtual server operation?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

But you've added the link to the official documentation that explains `##vso`:

> Logging commands are how tasks and scripts communicate with the agent.
> They cover actions like creating new variables, marking a step as
> failed, and uploading artifacts.

You can use it with print commands in your custom scripts in pipelines:

- bash/cmd

  ```
  echo "##vso[some_action;some_parameters]message"
  ```
- PowerShell

  ```
  Write-Host "##vso[some_action;some_parameters]message"
  ```

Comment: Thanks to point that out. This is very weird. I notice some culture like to solve problems by adding more and more, not able to simplify. These days, Windows, Google products all become more and more difficult to use.

Comment: I think you wanted to know what it stands for, right? 
This answer is quoting your own link back to you.

Answer (score 1):

VSO stands for Visual Studio Online, which is part of Azure DevOps’ early roots, as explained in the wiki page linked by @sql-surfer in the comments.
[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azure_DevOps_Server#:~:text=On%2Dpremises%20vs.-,online,the%20Microsoft%20Azure%20cloud%20platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azure_DevOps_Server#:%7E:text=On%2Dpremises%20vs.-,online,the%20Microsoft%20Azure%20cloud%20platform)